# How to convert a three wire hall effect sensor to a 2 wire sensor?

Tags: sensor, electromagnetism, magnetics, hall-effect

Would there be any possibility to convert a three-wire hallsensor to a 2-wire equivalent.
The connections are a V+, GDD and OUT. 
The voltage between V+ & GDD would be 24V and the OUT port would reflect the influence of a magnetic field on the sensor.

I assume that if one would connect the wires in the correct way you could get an sum or subtraction hence enabling a 2-wire circuit.

Thank

Answer (score 6):

A two wire sensor surely implies that the device becomes one that operates as a current device. The current would vary between two levels depending upon the magnetic field sensed by the Hall device. You have not indicated if the sensor is an on/off type detector of if it is an analogue device intended to show the relative strength of the magnetic field detected. In either case your target implementation could be designed to work as a 4-20mA type device. For the on/off type design the circuit could simply switch between 4mA and 20mA. The analogue implementation would vary continuously over the 4 to 20mA range. You can find various 4-20mA circuit designs on the web but the easiest is to deploy an IC chip that performs the 4-20mA driver function. Two possibilities to use for this are the [Analog Devices AD5750](http://www.analog.com/en/specialty-amplifiers/instrumentation-amplifiers/ad5750/products/product.html) or the [Texas Instruments XTR117](http://www.ti.com/product/xtr117).

Comment: Note for those unfamiliar with 4-20mA current loop type sensors that these sensors are designed to operate from a DC voltage source bias of 12V or even 24V. The sensor design has to be such that it will work in all its modes with 4mA of bias current at some nominal/usable voltage drop across the sensor. The sensor device then also includes a programmable current passing element that varies the current according to the signal information that wants to be sent with 20mA representing the maximum signal level. Continued

Comment: From above - A 4-20mA sensor is normally connected to a reader device that supplies the DC voltage bias for the 2-wire sensor loop and a load resistor device. The reader measures the voltage drop across the load resistor to determine the amount of current in the loop from the sensor. A typical two state sensor may be a proximity switch that toggles the current between 4 and 20mA based on the switch state. A temperature sensor may have 4mA represent -40C and 20mA represent 120C. The reader scales and offsets the detected current level back to on/off or an analogue value for temperature.

Comment: You can assume it's an on/off kind of sensor.

Answer (score 3):

Part number and link to datasheet of actual part is highly desirable.

I assume that it will run on a range of voltages including some below 24V.

Feed via a resistor that drops a few volts.
Arrange sensor output to draw additional current so that IR drop will increase and be detectable.
eg See diagram below and assumptions in text. "Main load" represents the sensor electronics core load and "Active" is an additional load switched into circuit when the output is active. This is only an example system -  other similar ones will come to mind with this as "catalyst".

If the main sensor electronics draw 5mA and the sensor output is designed to add about the same again then the voltage across the 1k resistor will double when the sensor operates.

[image]

Assume as an example:

- Will operate on 10-30V
- Draws say 5 mA
- Output is open drain.
- Feed via 1k
- Feed wires = negligible compared to 1k.
- output draws another 5 mA when activated.

Other assumptions will work but in the absence of you supplying real ones these provide an example.

Feed from 24V 1k resistor will drop 5V at 5mA so sensor sees 19V. .

When Hall switch operates the extra 5 mA will reduce voltage after resistor to 14V. Detect this 19V to 14V swing as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The way that pops to mind is to package it with a battery.  That way external connections are Ground and Out.